# How to draw Venn diagrams (especially: colored the intersection) using \node in Latex with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

There are plenty of examples show how to draw Venn diagrams using \clip command, such as
https://texample.net/tikz/examples/set-operations-illustrated-with-venn-diagrams/

However, all those examples directly draw a circle or other shapes. I prefer to draw all the shapes via \node command, cause it is easy to place nodes using relative placement.
I do not know how to use \clip command with \node command. Besides, the meaning of clip command is very hard to follow for me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Related: [Q53184](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53184), [Q44897](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44897)